# Google Maps, Android serialisation format

Tags: binary-analysis, android, java

I've come across an SQLite database (gmm_storage.db) used by Google Maps on Android, and I'm unsure as to how the data it contains is serialised. For example:

[image: Blob extracted from Google Maps Android database]

I'm saying serialised, as from the header 0xACED it appears to be a Java serialised object.  However, as I have no idea what the serialised class actually looks like, I've been unable to deserialise it.

I'm also not entirely sure it's standard Java serialisation, as I've tried a number of different tools, and Java itself,  and all of them report that the stream is corrupt.

You can see some references to standard Java classes, such as java/util/Set, but also a lot of smaller references to things like 'fic', or 'vot'.  I'm guessing these are either obfuscated class names, or they are part of some kind of lookup/offset table.

My other guess is that as it's a Google product, it's probably using a Google serialisation library, like GSON or protobuf, but the data doesn't look like either of those.

Anyone come across this before, or can shine some light on it?

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the app and finding the code which reads this db?

Comment: I haven't no.  I was hoping to avoid doing that, but it's certainly an option.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Are we allowed to reverse eng. Google Maps? If yes I'm on!

Comment: @Biswapriyo check your local laws but AFAIK in most jurisdictions reverse engineering is allowed for interoperability purposes etc.

Comment: @Tony Where and how did you get the database file?

Comment: I pulled it from a rooted Android device.  It's in /data/app/com.google.android.appls.maps-1

I've decompiled the APK, but it's heavily obfuscated.  So the odd names in the binary are indeed the class names.  I'm not sure what's going on with it, but the data in the file seems to mostly follow the Java serialization specification, however there is something funky going on.

Comment: I can not find any database file there. There is a similar name `libgmm-jni.so` file.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, there isn't a solution really.  It's going to be a matter of reversing engineering the structure, or trying to find the .proto file that describes the layout.